# Force reset postgres user on psql

Tags: postgresql

I learn a bit about DBA to help my coworkers. In the meanwhile, I forgot postgres local password and need to reset it. Since I see it is a common mistake, there are plenty of answers about change the file `/etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf` access permission from `md5` to `peer` down below the rows. However, the error below persists.

`psql: error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Is there any force way to reset such a fundamental user password? Does reinstallation do the work?

Best regards.

Comment: _down below the rows_ -- that's likely your problem. The very first line in `pg_hba.conf` that matches the connection will be used, with no fallback. You probably want to add your `peer` line at the beginning of the file instead.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank btw. Have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Put the following three lines *at the beginning* of `pg_hba.conf`:

```
local  all  postgres                trust
host   all  postgres  127.0.0.1/32  trust
host   all  postgres  ::1/128       trust
```

Then reload or restart PostgreSQL.  After that, you will be able to login *from the database server machine* without a password.

After you are done, remove the three lines and reload again to restore the original configuration.